# Cannot change variables using html inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

The problem I am having is that I cannot change elements of a variable.

I have tried many different ways, but I am struggling to take a input from HTML and changing a JS variable.

What I am making will include a random character generator in the future so changing parts of the variable is key if this is the correct way of doing it.

I have been using variables like this in Javascript:

```
let Player = {
  name: "Alex", 
  age: 20,
  Height: 190,
};
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot change elements of the variable. They way I have been trying is this:

```
document.getElementById("PlayerNameInput").innerHTML = Player.name
```

Any alternatives and/or better ways to get the same result? Changing the variable properties multiple times is a needed part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the **value** property of an **input** element and change the property of the object to its value.

If you set the **name** of the input *identical* to a property in the object things will be very smooth:

In your *html*:

```
<body>
  <input placeholder="First name" type="text" name="firstName"><br>
  <input placeholder="Last name" type="text" name="lastName"><br>
  <input placeholder="Hobby" type="text" name="hobby">
  <script src="changeObjFromInput.js"></script>
</body>
```

In your *script* **changeObjFromInputjs**:

```
let person = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  hobby: ''
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let input = e.target.closest('input');
  if (!input) { return; }
  person[input.name] = input.value;
  console.log(person);
});
```

**Edit:**
Or did you mean the other way around, from object to input fields, we can do that too, **value** is both readable and writeable:

```
let person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  hobby: 'fishing'
}

for (let key in person) {
  document.querySelector(`input[name=${key}]`).value = person[key];
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let input = e.target.closest('input');
  if (!input) { return; }
  person[input.name] = input.value;
  console.log(person);
});
```

Comment: Here, you may want to prefer the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) (or [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)) event instead of the `keyup` event. Also, I believe your code would be well-placed in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/13561410).

Comment: Yes, those handlers would be less 'intense' - just change to them if you want to. I chose 'keyup' because it demonstrated what happened in a direct way together with the console.log.  

Didn't know about Stack Snippets, will try that next time. Thanks fro the tip, Oskar :)

Comment: It has worked, I will try some other methods like what Oskar Grosser suggested as well. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you mean is like this. code `innerHTML` is used for set elements eg `.innerHTML = "<div>New Elm</div>"`

```js
let Player = {
  name: "Alex", 
  age: 20,
  Height: 190,
};

// get value from `html`
Player.name = document.getElementById("PlayerNameInput").value
// set new value to `html`
document.getElementById("PlayerNameInput").value = Player.name
console.log(Player)
```

```html
<input id="PlayerNameInput" value="John">
```